# accidentally closed cmd while updating pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to update pandas using
`conda update pandas` when accidentally I closed the cmd window.

now conda does not work anymore and spyder as well. 
if I try to run spyder.exe I get:

```
from PyQt5.Qtwidgets import * 
importerror: DLL load failed: The specific module could not be found
```

Do you know how to fix this issue?